# Static date in selected column as formula change value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to accomplish this through excel macro:

In my workbook `Sheet1`, values are entered in Range (`A2:H20`) through formulae.

I also have Range (`J2:P20`) that will keep track of change of values in Range (`A2:H20`) with a Date stamp in this format `dd-mmm-yyyy`.

Now I want to do this:

- if a value is changed in `A2` the date stamp should reflect in `J2`
- if a value is changed in `A3` the date stamp should reflect in `J3`
- if a value is changed in `B2` the date stamp should reflect in `K2`
- if a value is changed in `B3` the date stamp should reflect in `K3`

And that goes the same with other cells within those ranges.

The date stamp should replace any existing date (if any one exist) in its respective cells.
If any cell in the Range (`A2:H20`) is `=0` or empty there should be no date stamp in the corresponding cell.

Comment: I think you mean Q20 instead of P20

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example worked up for just cell A2/J2. You'll have to extend the code if you want to use it for the entire range. The code below goes in the "Worksheet_Change" Procedure of your sheet. Part of the example is from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
'Code Example from Microsoft.com
'http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612


' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("A2:H20")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    'MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."  <--- Original Microsoft Example

    'Code to Check Value/Status of A2
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        Range("J2").Value = Now()
        Else
        Range("J2").Value = ""
        End If
    End If

End If
End Sub
```